# Randomly spawn objects in Game

Tags: java, random, game-physics

I am trying to build a simple java game that will randomly spawn enemies for users to shoot down.

My game calls a method 60 times every second. I would like it to randomly perform an action every once in a while, in this case, spawn an enemy.

I found that using when using `Math.random()` and saying for example, < 0.1, as in a 10% chance it spawns too much because of the 60 frames per second. I would greatly appreciate any suggestions as to make this work better.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Separate sleeping thread? Scratch that: timer?

Comment: Check of a certain amount of time has passed to generate a random number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two thoughts that might help you in this case.

1. Why not try lowering the chance of happening? In you example if this is happening too often at 10%, lower it to a much smaller number. For instance if you want it to happen say, every 1 seconds, you need a % chance similar to 1 / 60 = 0.016%. Same idea if you want to make it once every 5 seconds, 1/(60*5).
2. Have your value change based on the time since the last random object. For instance, start the % chance at 0.0001. Every time the method is called increase the chance of it happening by some small amount. That way it will eventually get called for certain, but could happen faster (e.g. You want this to happen at least every 10 seconds or so, but you might get it sooner then that randomly).

Comment: I ended up generating a random integer that represented 60ths of a second to wait before spawning a new enemy. Thanks very much for your time to help out.

Comment: Glad you were able to come up with a good solution that worked for you!